# opentbs conditional statement in docx

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

How to show and hide the label [Merk - Track - Type || Location - Certificate], so here goes : when I have a vehicle data, the data appears :

```
[xtable;block=tbs:page]
Merk        : [xtable.VehicleMerk;noerr]
Track       : [xtable.VehicleTrack;noerr]
Type        : [xtable.VehicleType;noerr]
```

and land data the data does not appear, and otherwise.

my full code :

```
[xtable;block=tbs:page]
Merk        : [xtable.VehicleMerk;noerr]
Track       : [xtable.VehicleTrack;noerr]
Type        : [xtable.VehicleType;noerr]
--------------------------------------------------
Location    : [xtable.LandLocation;noerr]
Certificate : [xtable.LandCertificate;noerr]
```

thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer also posted on the [OpenTBS forum](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php?thr=3384).

The simplest is this :
Put your vehicle information in a unique paragraph, and your land information in another unique paragraph..
Then use parameter magnet in order to make a conditional display on the paragraph.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Merk        : [xtable.VehicleMerk;noerr;magnet=tbs:p]
Track       : [xtable.VehicleTrack;noerr]
Type        : [xtable.VehicleType;noerr]
--------------------------------------------------
Location    : [xtable.LandLocation;noerr;magnet=tbs:p]
Certificate : [xtable.LandCertificate;noerr]
--------------------------------------------------
```